# Clean eye-wear without lens cleaner

Tags: cleaning, eyeglasses

Lens cleaner are expensive and aren't found affordable though. Which is best way to clean eye-wear? Can I use shampoo? or anything else would work better to get result same as lens cleaner?

Comment: If you are asking about contact lenses, you should edit your question to make it clear.